# Delete multiple files

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, delete-file

I'm trying to delete multiple files in same folder with vb.net, but I haven't succeed yet. Help please?

I tried

```
Dim FileToDelete1 As String
Dim FileToDelete2 As String
Dim FileToDelete3 As String
Dim FileToDelete4 As String
Dim FileToDelete5 As String

FileToDelete1 = Application.StartupPath & "\1.exe"
FileToDelete2 = Application.StartupPath & "\2.dll"
FileToDelete3 = Application.StartupPath & "\3.dll"
FileToDelete4 = Application.StartupPath & "\4.dll"
FileToDelete5 = Application.StartupPath & "\5.dll"

If System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete1 ) = True Then

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( FileToDelete1 )


ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete2 ) = True Then

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( FileToDelete2 )

ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete3 ) = True Then

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( FileToDelete3 )

ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete4 ) = True Then

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( FileToDelete4 )

ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete5 ) = True Then

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( FileToDelete5 )

End If
```

Comment: directory.getFiles(path,"\*.\*",SearchOption.toplevelonly) will fetch you all the files.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here.

First, `File.Exists` returns a Boolean value.
The `"=True"` is unnecessary because you're basically asking if `True=True`. Fortunately, it is.

Second, file existence or not it's not the only way to fail. For instance, if the file is in use, you'll get an exception. You should handle it.

Third, what if you need to delete a thousand files? Would you create a `String` for each one of them? There are better options, for instance, the `GetFiles` method which will return a `ReadOnly List of Strings`, each one representing one file.
I don't know your needs, but to catch the files you mention, the following call can be made:

`FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, {"?.exe", "?.dll"})`

It will get every EXE and DLL file if it's name consists in only one character.

Finally, notice that if the first condition is met, no other will be evaluated, hence no other file will be deleted.
With that implementation you'll need to run the program 5 times in order to delete every file.
GetFiles method solves this as well.

Additionally, consider importing namespaces so you don't need to prefix them in every method call.

Comment: Just loop the list. Each item represents one file.
Check @Div Tiwari 's answer

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to do some thing like this

```
Dim fileNames() as string={"1","2","3"}
Dim fileTypes() as string={"exe","dll"} 

directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Application.StartupPath)
  For each fileName as string in fileNames
    For each fileType as string in fileTypes
        if My.Computer.FileSystem .FileExists (fileName &"."& fileType) then
          try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( fileName &"."& fileType )
          catch ex As Exception
            '**** processings related with exception.
          end try
        endif
        'Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, fileName &"." & fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        'For Each FileToDelete as string in files
        '   My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( FileToDelete )
        'Next
    Next
  Next
```

Comment: No, I don't want to delete all files containing .Dll or .Exe. I need to delete specific files, from the same directory as where the actual program is. @ Sérgio Ribeiro: I guess that would work, but how do I remove the results of that search?

Comment: You should probably put the actual deletion inside of a try-catch block, in case any of the files are in use or something else goes wrong.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: Yes! you are right. But i think it should be for another day of tutorial. :)

Comment: Okay I'll try to close this. I didn't make try-catch for it, I am using timer for it so any file isn't in use. Edit: Didn't find it.. Reported the op so moderator can mark this as solved.

Comment: @user2404495 Div posted the procedure to accept an answer; follow that link for information.